# Small change in my regular expression validating surnames

Tags: regex, validation

I know that validation of surnames (by using regular expression) is usually not practiced (except null validation). However, I have different opinion.

I have produced following regular expression:

```
^(?![^-]+-[^-]+-)[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z-]+$
```

It basically rejects special characters, and accepts diactrics which exists in my native language.

However there is a one special case, for which this regular expression does not work.

Accepted OK - "Travolta-Smith"

Accepted OK - "Travolta-Smith Jovi"

**Accepted but not OK - "Travolta - Smith"**

**Accepted but not OK - "Travolta    -Smith"**

**Accepted but not OK - "Travolta-  Smith"**

White spaces causes the problem, there should not be any whitespaces next to the hyphen.

Could you give me some small hint? How to reject such a case?

I've spend a lot of time on defining this regular expression...

Thank you for any response.

Comment: Try [`^(?!.* - )[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]+(?:-[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/GWWvuY/1). Or just add `(?!.* - )` after `^` in your regex.

Comment: @wiktor. Thank you. Only one case left: "Travolta   -Smith" and "Travolta-   Smith  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add another negative lookahead to your regex:

```
^(?!.*(?: -|- ))(?![^-]+-[^-]+-)[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z-]+$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8FS79A/1)

The `(?!.*(?: -|- ))` will fail the match if after any 0+ chars other than line break chars there is a space followed with `-` or `-` followed with space.

To make the regex a bit more efficient, your negative lookahead can be removed if the consuming pattern is unrolled a bit like

```
^(?!.*(?: -|- ))[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]+(?:-[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]+)?$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM2bOE/1)

Here, `[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]+` matches 1+ chars defined in the character class (with the `-` taken out) and then `(?:-[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]+)?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of `-` followed 1+ chars defined in the `[a-ząęłóźżćśńŃŻŹŁÓ'ĄĘ A-Z]` character class. So, only 1 `-` is allowed in the string.

Comment: Thank You for answer and explanation.